# Expressing the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $(x_i-x_j)^2$ variables in term of the elementary polynomials in the $x_k$ variables

Tags: symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials

Let $n>1$ be an integer and let $P$ be a multivariate symmetric polynomial in $n(n-1)/2$ variables.

Let us define the multivariate polynomial $Q_P$ in n variables as:

$Q_P(x_1,...,x_n)=P\left(\{(x_i-x_j)^2\}_{i>j}\right)$

(The order of the variablesing inside $P$ shouldn't matter thanks to its symmetry).

It turns out that $Q_P$ is a symmetric polynomial, and so I should be able to express it in term of the elementary symmetric polynomials in n variables.

In the particular case of $P$ being itself a elementary symmetric polynomial in $n(n-1)/2$ variables, is there an expression for the decomposition of $Q_P$ in term of elementary symmetric polynomials in n variables?

The only vaguely related thing I found is the expression of the subdiscriminants as determinants of symmetric matrices with entries equals to power sums of the $x_i$ variables (and the power sums can be related to the elementary symmetric polynomials) (see Basu: Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry)

but subdiscriminants don't seem to form a basis for the space of symmetric polynomials in the $n(n-1)/2$ variables (but maybe they can be completed to form one? Or the determinant technique can be adapted?)

Comment: It is not hard to express the power sums via power sums. Then you may use Newton identities to relate power sums and elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: If I understand correctly the strategy is to consider the case for $P$ power sum in the $(x_i-x_j)^2$ variables and express $Q_P$ as power sums in the $x_k$ variables and then use Newton identities to re express everything in term of elementary symmetric polynomial? While I still haven't found explicitly a formula it looks like (using a CAS and the integer sequence site) that effectively the relationship is simple (and can be expressed through binomial coefficients). Thanks

Comment: Yes, the strategy is this. You start with $\sum_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)^{2k}=\frac12\sum_{i,j} (x_i-x_j)^{2k}=\frac12 \sum_{s=0}^{2k}(-1)^s \binom{2k}s (\sum x_i^s)(\sum x_j^{2k-s})$.